# Android Studio MultiLineText text moving upwards

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, multiline

Hi I am going through a training from Google and I have an issue with the MultiLine TextView.

Everytime when I code the example myself when I press enter on my phone to create a new line the text entered moves upwards why is this the case ?

Here is the code from the example that Google provides.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Strong"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.droidcafeinput.OrderActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/order_label_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="@string/name_label_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_textview" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_name_hint"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/name_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/address_label_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_address_hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/address_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/address_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/phone_label_string"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_text"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_phone_hint"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/phone_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phone_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/note_label_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_note_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/note_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/note_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delivery_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/choose_delivery_method"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/note_text" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delivery_label">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/sameday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/same_day_messenger_service" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/nextday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/next_day_ground_delivery" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/pickup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/pick_up" />
</RadioGroup>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/label_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phone_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Message"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.452"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.712" /
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture the Multiline Text View somehow moves upwards instead of downwards. When I implement it on my own and use the inputType:"textMultiLine". How come this issue is caused as well as why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view `editTextTextMultiLine` keep changing its position cause of its constraint attribute . Your design view -

[image]

You can constraint `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` of your RadioGroup . Suppose define a ID of radiogroup then use constraint value of `editTextTextMultiLine` as below -

```
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radiogroup"
```

Full layout file -

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Strong"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.droidcafeinput.OrderActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/order_label_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="@string/name_label_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_textview" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_name_hint"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/name_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/address_label_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_address_hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/address_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/address_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/phone_label_string"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_text"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_phone_hint"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/phone_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phone_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/note_label_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_note_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/note_label"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/note_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delivery_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/choose_delivery_method"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/note_text" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/delivery_label">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/sameday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/same_day_messenger_service" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/nextday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/next_day_ground_delivery" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/pickup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/pick_up" />
</RadioGroup>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/label_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phone_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Message"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radiogroup" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Desgn view looks like now-

[image]